# Group tab item "li" as drop down when tab items exceed 5?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I tried to dynamically add new tab item, and group it as a drop down if the tab item exceed 5.

However, the fifth tab item on ward is not formatted well as the first, second, third and fourth tab item including the drop down list, seem like they are not applied the class of jquery-ui tab at all.

How could I make my drop down list tab functioning well as another tab? Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#tabs").tabs();
  $("button#add-tab").click(function() {
    var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul.main-tab li").length + 1;
    // alert(num_tabs);
    if (num_tabs > 5) {
      $('li.more-tab').css('display', 'block');
      $("div#tabs ul.dropdown-menu").append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</a></li>");
      $("div#tabs").append("<div id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</div>");
      $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    } else {
      // alert(2);
      $("div#tabs ul.main-tab").append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</a></li>");
      $("div#tabs").append("<div id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</div>");
      $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id='tabs'>
  <ul class="main-tab">
    <li><a href='#tab1'>#1</a></li>
    <li class="more-tab" style="display: none;">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        more tab
       </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id='add-tab'>Add tab</button>
```